# JavaFX how to clear TextField when mouse is clicked on it

Tags: java, javafx

I have a problem with chosing correct action on TextField. On Java  class:

```java
@FXML
private TextField projectNameInput;
    
@FXML
private void clearProjectName(MouseEvent event) {

    // some if - else statements
    projectNameInput.clear();
}
```

On FXML it looks like this:

```
<TextField fx:id="projectNameInput" onMouseClicked="#clearProjectName" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
```

I tried most options, in Java I tried (as arg) Event, MouseEvent, ActionEvent, combined with FXML `onAction`, etc but no luck. What kind of action should I choose that when I click the mouse button on TextField it will be automatically cleared?

Comment: It works for me as you show it. Make sure with some printing to the console that the event occurs.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. There were no exceptions, just needed to reload class. Probably Eclipse lag.

Comment: `how to clear TextField when mouse is clicked on it` - what about when the user tabs to the text field? Don't assume a user will only use the mouse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
TextField1.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, numeric_Validation(5));
    
AutoControl.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        TextField1.clear();
    }
}
```